# unable to initialize kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I was learning to set up a single node Kubernetes cluster but was not able to initalise it. Ive done some research and have done a few fixes but still couldn't get my kubelet running. Can someone help tks a lot!
My environment (on my Ubuntu 64 bit, VMware Workstation 17 Player ) :
Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename:    jammy

The errors are shown below.

```
liming@liming-virtual-machine-3:/$ sudo kubeadm init


[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.26.0
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
[certs] Generating "ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver" certificate and key
[certs] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local liming-virtual-machine-3] and IPs [10.96.0.1 192.168.2.132]
[certs] Generating "apiserver-kubelet-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [liming-virtual-machine-3 localhost] and IPs [192.168.2.132 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [liming-virtual-machine-3 localhost] and IPs [192.168.2.132 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/healthcheck-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver-etcd-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "sa" key and public key
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.

Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
    timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
    - The kubelet is not running
    - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
    - 'systemctl status kubelet'
    - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.
Here is one example how you may list all running Kubernetes containers by using crictl:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
    Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock logs CONTAINERID'
error execution phase wait-control-plane: couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
```

```
liming@liming-virtual-machine-3:~$ systemctl status kubelet
× kubelet.service - kubelet
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor pres>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-12-26 17:05:54 +08; 2h >
   Main PID: 3223 (code=exited, status=217/USER)
        CPU: 1ms

Dec 26 17:05:54 liming-virtual-machine-3 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Schedule>
Dec 26 17:05:54 liming-virtual-machine-3 systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet.
Dec 26 17:05:54 liming-virtual-machine-3 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Start re>
Dec 26 17:05:54 liming-virtual-machine-3 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed w>
Dec 26 17:05:54 liming-virtual-machine-3 systemd[1]: Failed to start kubelet.
lines 1-11/11 (END)
```

1. Fixes Ive done beforehand are shown below .

```
$ iptables -F
$ swapoff -a
$ free -m
$ kubeadm reset
$ kubeadm init
```

Ive also set the docker cgroup driver to systemd

```
docker info |grep -i cgroup


Cgroup Driver: systemd
Cgroup Version: 2
cgroupns
```

Below is the kubelet log:

```
liming@liming-virtual-machine-3:~$ journalctl -xeu kubelet
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit kubelet.service has been scheduled, as the>
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Dec 26 17:05:54 liming-virtual-machine-3 systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit kubelet.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit kubelet.service has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 3203 and the job result is done.
Dec 26 17:05:54 liming-virtual-machine-3 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Start re>
Dec 26 17:05:54 liming-virtual-machine-3 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed w>
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit kubelet.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-c>
Dec 26 17:05:54 liming-virtual-machine-3 systemd[1]: Failed to start kubelet.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit kubelet.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit kubelet.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 3203 and the job result is failed.
```

My swap should have already been disabled as shown below.

```
liming@liming-virtual-machine-3:~$ systemctl list-units --type=swap --state=active
  UNIT LOAD ACTIVE SUB DESCRIPTION
0 loaded units listed.
```

Comment: Is kubelet service running? you can check it `systemctl status kubelet`

Comment: no  it returns error. ive added the error above.